# mail() php return true but mail not received

Tags: php, email

Trying to send email from my ubuntu 14.04 localhost.
I'm usinf mail() of php. It returns true but i'm not receiving any email.
Tryed with different providers (gmail, yahoo).
But everytime i get this message in mail.log:

```
Aug 18 15:05:10 salvatore-vaio sm-mta[5378]: s7ID59ib005376: to=<dibenedettosa@yahoo.it>, ctladdr=<www-data@salvatore-vaio.huawei.com> (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=121979, relay=mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net. [188.125.69.79], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection refused by mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net.
```

i've tried:

```
telnet mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net 465
```

But i receive the following message:

telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable

Also tryied:

```
ping -c 3  mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net
```

And got this:

```
--- mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 168.969/445.192/995.807/389.344 ms
```

Also here my php.ini:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.mail.yahoo.com      
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 465
auth_username = myid
auth_password = mypass

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = dibenedettosa@yahoo.it

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

Cant't find any solution...

Comment: What are you using for a mail server?

Comment: Consider Using a library like PHPMailer & if  you want to send over an smtp-server, you may use the one from gmail

Comment: On relying at `mail()`'s return true: PHP's `mail()` function will return True if the message was accepted by the SMTP server for delivery. True does *not* imply that the message contains a valid email address or that the message was actually delivered.

Answer (score 6):

You are not allowed using yahoo mail servers for relaying your emails. You need to authenticate to use it. This is possible with `mail()` through config files but it is easier using `PHPMailer` or `SwiftMail`.

Your Mail transfer agent: `salvatore-vaio (sm-mta)`

Is not allowed to use `mx-eu.mail.am0.yahoodns.net`

This is to prevent spam.

For the sending mail address `www-data@salvatore-vaio.huawei.com`:

```
nsaboard:~# host salvatore-vaio.huawei.com
Host salvatore-vaio.huawei.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

You need to setup an `MX` DNS record and different techniques to increase reputation. (like SPF and DKIM.).

If you are using yahoo directly, set your `sendmail_from` to the yahoo address.

Message deferring can be caused by several things.

Comment: I am trying with PHPMailer but i get Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. I am using the example posted here: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: @SalvatoreDibenedetto can you post the configuration please

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that you need to identify yourself on your smtp.

Check your php.ini for the smtp server. Change the smtp to one you can actually use.

Comment: Here what in my php.ini:[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.mail.yahoo.com  
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 465
auth_username = myid
auth_password = mypass

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = dibenedettosa@yahoo.it

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"

Answer (score 0):

Finally i fixed.
As @DanFromGermany reccomended i downloaded PHPMailer from [here](http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and used the example posted in that page.

Also i had to face a second issue regarding the "two step autentication" of gmail.
This need to generate a specific password for the application that allow the login.
Find [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1173270?hl=en) the google documentation

After that it worked!